# In Docker, how to allow connection to Postgres in external host?

Tags: python, docker

I have a Python application that connects to a Postgresql db in external host. When I dockerized and composed my application I noticed that Docker does not allow connection in my postgres. Also Postgres is not a Docker image. What should I do?

Comment: You can connect from inside a container to the localhost of the Docker host using the magic DNS name `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: If you can connect with yours DB from host, you should put your docker in "host" network : _Host networks are best when the network stack should not be isolated from the Docker host, but you want other aspects of the container to be isolated._ from https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: Is the container running outside Docker on the same host, or in a different host entirely?  How do you have it configured in your application, and what error are you getting?

Comment: my application is in host 10.3.0.x and postgres is in host 10.3.0.y. I get the error when inside the application i try to connect to the db for the first time

Comment: can you connect to Postgresql at all from 10.3.0.x? Are the Postgresql ports correctly setup?

Comment: You shouldn’t need any special setup on the Docker side (and you definitely don’t need host networking).  What error are you getting?  Can you provide enough of a [mcve] in the question to avoid guessing about details like database connection strings?

Comment: @halfer Does `host.docker.internal` work for linux now?

Comment: @atline: it does, yes.

Comment: @halfer Would you mind share some link? As I just see [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds) and [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

Comment: @halfer I use `docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash`, and install `iputils-ping`, then strange, `root@d62a3f6e140e:/# ping host.docker.internal` shows: `ping: host.docker.internal: Name or service not known`, and version `Version:          18.09.1`

Comment: Ah, my apologies @atline - I have just tried it and it does not seem to work. I use it for a client (on a Windows host) and it is fine. On my Linux laptop it fails immediately, whereas a random string causes a delay; that indicates to me that it is recognised but not working. I wonder [whether this is of any help](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/8xeqe6/hostdockerinternal_on_linux_sort_of/)?

Comment: Perhaps then it is Windows only; I was fairly sure I had used it in Linux project, but perhaps not.

Comment: Yeah, never mind, I just curious that it work now, as I see [this](https://dev.to/bufferings/access-host-from-a-docker-container-4099) before, thanks for clarify.